# SharePoint 2013 upload images in site assets using jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

We have a requirement to upload images using jquery using input file picker. Is there any services or rest api available to upload images in site assets.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/upload-a-file-by-using-the-rest-api-and-jquery).
Here you can get the idea how to achieve your goal. I have never tried this, if it works please let me know :)